# Pandas modify table into list when reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, google-colaboratory

### I ran into this issue on google colab: the spreadsheet turns into a list with `read_csv`

The original file is a 3 cols, 6219 rows (includes column header) table of protein sequence:
|Unnamed: 0|aaSequence|medianBrightness|
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|0|MSQEGDYGRWTISSSDESEEEKPKPDK|80000000.0|
|1|MSQEGDYGRWTISSSDESEEEKPKPDK|100000000.0|

Not sure if my table is showing, it looks like this in preview (protein truncated):

[image]

And I ran this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/hydrolase_padded.csv')
```

When I print `df` out, it returns a list with numbers I never seen in my dataset, length 6218:

```
[3500, 3605, 4804, 300, 2832, 6106, 2057, 4958, 3468, 2944, 4197, 3164, 5108, 679, ....]
```

Anyone knows what could be happening?

Comment: does the `df` just have the one column with those numbers? or are there 3 columns?
what do you get when you run `df.info()`?

Comment: Just one, I will check that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is separated by '|', try adding the `delimiter="|"` param. Either, are you sure you are loading the correct file? can you provide provide it to test it?

Comment: You are right, I converted the dataframe to list later before I printed it out! Also I will try "|"